# php = insert working but want to check if in db already based on one field

Tags: php

Have a working system where I am posting news articles.  I sometimes add the same one twice and want to avoid this.  So how can I alter my insert statement to first check for a match on the field named 'title' to see if it is equal to the title I have in the record I am trying to submit?

Here is php code I use, as it was done for me since I am a PHP novice but I do not know how to check for the title=title and then not add it if it finds it or to add it if it doesnt find a match:

```
$result = mysql_query("
insert into news (
     catalogid,
     title,
     intro,
     content,
     viewnum,
     adddate,
     rating,
     ratenum,
     source,
     sourceurl,
     isdisplay,
     isfeature,
     subip,
     vsent,
     timesubmitted) 
values             
     ('1',
     '$title',
     '$intro',
     '$content',
     '0',
     '$subdate',
     '$source',
     '$icheck',
     'N/A',
     '$sourceurl',
     '$isapp',
     '0',
     '127.0.0.1',
     '0',
     '$tsdate')"
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Set a `UNIQUE` key on the field you want to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

There are database-specific tricks like [`on duplicate key update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), but typically you simply test for the existence of a record with the same key via a `select`. If the record exists, you `update` it with the new data, otherwise you `insert` a new record.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a check query before inserting , like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT catalogid from news WHERE title='".$yourTitle."'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql) < 1) {
     //add your insert query here
 }
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE `title`=$title");
if (!$result)
{
   // your code INSERT
   $result = mysql_query("
insert into news (
     catalogid,
     title,
     intro,
     content,
     viewnum,
     adddate,
     rating,
     ratenum,
     source,
     sourceurl,
     isdisplay,
     isfeature,
     subip,
     vsent,
     timesubmitted) 
values             
     ('1',
     '$title',
     '$intro',
     '$content',
     '0',
     '$subdate',
     '$source',
     '$icheck',
     'N/A',
     '$sourceurl',
     '$isapp',
     '0',
     '127.0.0.1',
     '0',
     '$tsdate')"
);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with a single INSERT statement, at least not directly. If you set the title field in your database table to UNIQUE, you can prevent MySQL from inserting a record with a duplicate title. You will need to detect if the mysql_query function returns FALSE; if it does, you know a duplicate record was inserted and you can handle this however you see fit.